# Insert array of data in Database using MySQL,PHP and angular.js

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, angularjs

I need one help for inserting array of data into database using PHP,MySQL and angular.js.Let me to explain my code.Suppose i have the below set of data which will insert into database.

```
$scope.listOfData=[
    0:{'name':raj,'email':raj@gmail.com,'rollno':11,'subject`:abc},
    1:{'name':raja,'email':raja@gmail.com,'rollno':13,'subject`:ab},
    2:{'name':raja1,'email':raja1@gmail.com,'rollno':113,'subject`:anb},
    ....................................................................
    .....................................................................

    20:{'name':raja1,'email':raja1@gmail.com,'rollno':113,'subject`:anb},
];
```

I have 20 numbers of data in one object and i have only 4 field in database (`i.e-name,email,rollno,subject`).When user will click on submit button these 20 nos of data will insert in DB in 20 rows.Here i need how it can be done in php. In this below code i am declaring the submit function.

```
$scope.addData=function(){
   $http({
        method:'POST',
        url: "php/timetable/addTimeTable.php",
        data:$scope.listOfTimeData,
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
    }).then(function successCallback(response){
        //Success callback
    },function errorCallback(response) {
        //Error callback
    });
};
```

Here i need how i will pass the all data to php file and insert all data in Mysql (`Lets say table name-db_user`) DB at a time in a loop.Please help me.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php

Comment: `$scope.listOfData` is invalid.

Comment: @SarjanDesai : its ok i was just trying to display the console output of `listOfData`.But my requirement is something else.

Answer (score 0):

Format of your `$scope.listOfData` is invalid. it should be like

```
$scope.listOfData=[
{'name':raj,'email':raj@gmail.com,'rollno':11,'subject`:abc},
{'name':raja,'email':raja@gmail.com,'rollno':13,'subject`:ab},
{'name':raja1,'email':raja1@gmail.com,'rollno':113,'subject`:anb},
....................................................................
.....................................................................

{'name':raja1,'email':raja1@gmail.com,'rollno':113,'subject`:anb},
];
```